# Delete a file without having permission

Tags: root, permissions

Can you delete a file in linux without having nor permission or root access?

Thank you.

Comment: please elaborate. which folder? you can delete any files without permission in your `/home/user/` folder and `/tmp/` folder, other than that, big NO.

Comment: what about /opt folder?

Comment: again, big NO to other folders

Comment: You might be interested in reading [How does vim steal root owned files?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/58880/23363)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can delete any files without permission in your `/home/user/` folder and in `/tmp/` folder you can delete some files that aren't owned by root, other than that, big NO.

Comment: You cannot delete files that you don't own from /tmp. Only root has that privilege. Why? Because the folder /tmp has the restricted deletion flag set. `ls -dl /tmp` gives `drwxrwxrwt 12 root root 4096 Jan  3 18:05 /tmp` The `t` in `drwxrwxrwxt` shows this.

Comment: yep, i just check that, thanks. i'll update the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To delete a file ,permissions on files have no importance.To delete a file you should have proper permission (write permission) on directory that is housing it.